# splice deletes from an array and also from its parent array - strange issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, splice, array-splice

Hi I have this simple script in my code,

```
var c = [{a: 'apple'},{b: 'ball'},{c: 'ball'},{d: 'ball'}];
console.log(c); //prints 3 objects
var d = c; 
d.splice(0, 3);         
console.log(c); //prints 1 object        
console.log(d); //prints 1 object
```

What is strange to me  is both c and d after splice results same thing (after deleting 3 objects from c whereas I have deleted from d only not c). 
Using `d.splice(0, 3)` it should delete from 'd' why would it delete from 'c' too ??? any ideas ?? where am I missing something, pls guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var d = c;
```

This is referencing the array, not duplicating it.

To duplicate it and make `d` a completely separate array, use `.slice(0)`

```
var d = c.slice(0)
```

Comment: var d = c.splice(0);  
            d.splice(0, 3);         
            console.log(c); // prints blank         
            console.log(d); // prints 1 object

Comment: @Luckyy - Sorry, my mistake. The method names are very similar, it's actually *`slice`* (no *p*) - see my update above.